# Read More link in Drupal Advanced Poll module not respecting the path alias

Tags: drupal

I have an Advanced Poll on my home page and for some reason the Read More URL shows up as:
http://www.mydomain.com/node/265

But, in the Poll I have the URL path setting set to this... and it works great directly:
http://www.mydomain.com/poll/name-of-my-poll

Does anyone know why the poll doesn't use the path alias or how I can fix it?

Thanks much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out...

I had to put something like this in my template.php file:

```
function mytheme_advpoll_view_block_poll($nid) {
    $node = advpoll_view(node_load($nid), FALSE, FALSE);
    $output = '';
    if ($node && $node->status && $node->active && $node->start_date < time() && $node->end_date > time()) {
        $output .= '<h3>' . $node->title . '</h3>';

    unset($node->content['body']); 
        $output .= drupal_render($node->content);
        $output .= l('Read more...', drupal_get_path_alias('node/' . $nid));

    }
    return $output;
}
```